# Wordpress - add class to a main div in specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, css-selectors, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a certain page where I need just to change background color only in that page and this page structure starts like:

```
<body class="...">
   <div class="start-class">
      ......
   </div>
</body>
```

and I was thinking to put in `functions.php` like:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_css');
function my_css( $classes ) {
     if ( is_page(82) )
        find div that has specific "start-class" because it doesn't have any id
          $classes[] = 'my-custom';
 
     return $classes; 
}
```

is there a way to add it?.. thanks to all!! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I decided to apply total transparency on all levels of container elements inside body with:

```
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.0) !important;
```

wherever applicable so I could use just a background inside body with that `add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_css');` I said in the post so that makes my life easier... thanks to all anyway @Johannes , @Broe , @Rahul Srivastava !
Cheers !!!

Answer (score 1):

If you change / add the following php code to your `body` tag in the `header.php` file...

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> >
```

..., Wordpress will automatically add "body classes", among them a `page-id-xxx`, where "xxx" stands for an individual id number per page that corresponds to the page id in the database. Then you can create a CSS rule with a `background-color` for that id (`#page-id-xxx { background-color: #abc; }`  and add it either to the general stylesheet or via the customizer only to that page.

Comment: HI @Johannes , thanks for your answer but I meant like adding a new class inside `<div>` element side by that `"start-class"` like substituting it because that div already covers the entire page....

Comment: I know that you meant that, but in CSS there are no selectors for parent elements, so the described method is one way to still achieve the desired result. Another one would be to use jQuery/javascript, but with css alone there is no way.

Comment: So use `.page-id-xxx .start-class { ... }` then.

Comment: @CBroe Well, OP wrote "find div that has specific start-class because it doesn't have any id", so apparently the page ID isn't there yet, hence my answer...

Comment: @Johannes I think they meant that the `.start-class` element itself has no specific ID. Calling `body_class()` to add the classes to body is the de-facto "standard" that almost every theme adheres to.

Comment: @Johannes  , that ‵<div>‵ covers the entire body like the body is behind the ‵<div>‵ , in fact I already tried to add the new class in body using ‵add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_css');‵ and didn't applied the ‵background-color #red !important;‵ thing ... with chrome's debug I see like body's behind div....

Comment: Well, *can* use `.page-id-xxx .start-class { background-color: red !important; }` if you have already a page-id. In this case just make sure to have a colon (`:`) in there and not to write `#red` as you did, but either `red` without "#" OR a hex code like `#ff0000` for the color definition). If you don't have a page-id in `body` yet, use the method I described in my answer aditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to add body class for specific pages.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'custom_body_class');

    function custom_body_class($classes) {
        if (is_page(38034))
            $classes[] = 'new-class';
        return $classes;
}
```

Based on custom class you can change the background color of specific pages.also visit https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/